# How to tune a MLPRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, regression

I currently have a dataset with variables and observations. I want to predict a variable (demand), which is a continuous one, thus I need to use a Regression model. I tried with `Linear Regression`, and evaluated it using the `R2` metric, which was around `0.85`. I wanted to evaluate its performance with other models, and one of them was the `NNs`. I believe that Neural Networks are more suitable in other task like classification, nevertheless I wanted to give them a try.

I decided to use `scikit-learn` mainly because it offers both models (Linear Regression and Multi Layer Perceptron), the thing is that the `R2` metric was way too far and bad compared to the Linear Regression's one. Thus, I concluded that I am missing many important configurations. Below you can see my code and how the data comes.

My data has the following columns, only `demand` (which is my label), `population`,`gdp`, `day` and `year` are numerical continuous, the rest are categorical.

```
['demand','holy','gdp','population', 'day','year', 'f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4','f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19', 'f20', 'f21', 'f22', 'f23', 'g0', 'g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g4', 'g5', 'g6', 'g7', 'g8', 'g9', 'g10', 'g11']
```

This is what I actually do, I removed some outputs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math as math

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score



training_data, validation_data = np.split(data.sample(frac=1), [int(.8*len(data))])

linear_model = LinearRegression().fit(training_data[[c for c in data.columns if c != "demand"]], training_data[["demand"]])

validation_data_predictions = linear_model.predict(validation_data[[c for c in training_data.columns if c != "demand"]])

validation_predictions_pd = pd.DataFrame(data=validation_data_predictions, 
                                         index=validation_data.index.values,
                                         columns=["prediction"])

# join both pandas
result_df = validation_data.join(validation_predictions_pd, how="inner")

r2_error = r2_score(y_true=result_df[["demand"]], y_pred=result_df[["prediction"]], multioutput="uniform_average")

print(r2_error) # outputs 0.85


# NN section
clf = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,), max_iter=100000)

neural_model = clf.fit(training_data[[c for c in training_data.columns if c != "demand"]], training_data[["demand"]])

validation_data_predictions = neural_model.predict(validation_data[[c for c in training_data.columns if c != "demand"]])

validation_predictions_pd = pd.DataFrame(data=validation_data_predictions, 
                                     index=validation_data.index.values,
                                     columns=["prediction"])

result_df = validation_data.join(validation_predictions_pd, how="inner")

r2_error = r2_score(y_true=result_df[["demand"]], y_pred=result_df[["prediction"]], multioutput="uniform_average")
print(r2_error) # outputs 0.23
```

So, as you can see the NN´s performance is very poor. And I think its performance can be improved, any hints?

Comment: Alberto, could you please make your example reproducible? Define the `data` variable so that others can provide you a tangible help. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

1. MLP is sensitive to feature scaling. Have you normalzied your data?
2. Modify your network structure: add more hidden layers and change number of perceptrons of each layer
3. change activation function to sigmod/tanh/relu etc.

Comment: 4. Change learning rate: `learning_rate`,  `learning_rate_init`. 5. Toggle `early_stopping`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe is not that the NN's performance is bad, maybe you are just using the wrong metric for comparing them. Usually it is not a good idea to trust the R2 score for evaluating linear regression models with many regressors: in fact, the more regressors you put in your model the higher your R squared ([see this video for a quick explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjRrdb2x6dA)).

Anyway I think this question is more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com/